# Perl regex not containing round brackets

Tags: regex, perl, regex-negation

I have text like the following:

```
Hallo ich bin Pra Lebo, | (_S ich wurde 1974 in Südafrika geboren, S_) | (_B <marker
tag="1">denn</marker> meine Eltern, | beide Angehörige der Komtoru, | sind nach dem 
Umsturz ´73 ausgewandert. B_) | Trotz meiner auswärtigen Herkunft fühle ich mich Akritiri immer
noch sehr verbunden und ich hoffe, | dass wir heute eine gute Entscheidung treffen können. | Ich 
plädiere für ein parlamentarisches Regierungssystem, | damit die Kontrolle besser gegeben ist und 
damit so schreckliche Ereignisse sich nie wieder wiederholen können. |
```

I would like to a regex to match strings inside `(_S ... S_)`, another regex to match strings inside `(_B ...B_)` and a third one to match those spans that are not inside any of the above. Ideally, I would have three regexes. How would one go about doing this?

The first two problems are much easier and have been answered, however the third problem still remains. I need to match the largest strings not surrounded by any opening or closing round brackets. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex `(?<=\(_S)((.|\n)*?)(?=S_\))` for getting string inside `(_S` and `S_)`

**[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/cY9pQ4)**

Similarly you can use regex `(?<=\(_B)((.|\n)*?)(?=B_\))` for getting string inside `(_B` and `B_)`

**[Demo2](http://regex101.com/r/tS2rT5)**

To match these two , you can use :

```
(?:(?<=\(_S)((?:.|\n)*?)(?=S_\)))|(?:(?<=\(_B)((?:.|\n)*?)(?=B_\)))
```

**[Demo3](http://regex101.com/r/uS7zD1)**

To match string that are not enclosed in brackets  , you can use something like this :

```
(((?:^)|(?<=\)))(?:[^(])*)
```

**[Demo4](http://regex101.com/r/vU0cL3)**

Comment: Thanks, will try this in a second. Do you also have advice on how to do the third regex? Match anything that is not inside the brackets? This last regex should return two matches for my example above:
Match 1: `Hallo ich bin Pra Lebo,`
Match 2: `| Trotz meiner auswärtigen Herkunft fühle ich mich Akritiri immer noch sehr verbunden und ich hoffe, | dass wir heute eine gute Entscheidung treffen können. | Ich plädiere für ein parlamentarisches Regierungssystem, | damit die Kontrolle besser gegeben ist und damit so schreckliche Ereignisse sich nie wieder wiederholen können.`

Comment: Ok , I will check it and reply you.

Comment: OK, the first two regexes work like a charm. Thanks again. However, the split method returns many incorrect matches. To clarify: I would like to match the longest possible span of non-( containing strings.

Comment: @user1826452 Check Demo3 .

Comment: Hi Sujith - I already checked demo3, thanks for that. It it suitable for matching stuff inside the brackets. I would also like a third regex to match stuff NOT contained in the brackets - see my comment above.